# How do I generate 1000 random numbers between 0 and 9?

Tags: java, random, numbers, generator

How do I generate 1000 random numbers between 0 and 9 using values provided by the user?

1. The program needs to allow the user to select the values for fact,
   constant, modulus and a starting seed number.
2. It should generate 1000 random numbers between 0 and 9 using those values.
3. Store the number of times each number is generated in an array.
4. Output the distribution of the numbers at the end.

Here is what I've done till now but I've only got the user to input the information till now, so, I'm very far from having achieved number 2, 3 and 4.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int fact;
    int constant;
    int modulus;
    int seednumber;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input Fact: ");
    fact = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Input Const: ");
    constant = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Input M: ");
    modulus = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Input Seed: ");
    seednumber = scan.nextInt();

    int [] arrayBox;
    arrayBox = new int [10];
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
        arrayBox[i]=0;
      }

    int noOfNumberGenerated=0;
    while (noOfNumberGenerated<1000){
        seednumber=(((fact*seednumber)+constant)%modulus);
}
```

Comment: "I must start off by saying that I am new to Java. I have done this in C before but I don't really know how to finish this code in Java. I am learning it by myself, from what I get from the documents on Stackoverflow and NetBeans. I am doing a small exercise that i found on RosettaCode to learn more on Java but I need someone to help me with the coding.” How is this relevant to the question?

Comment: Which numbers between 0 and 9? Integers? Do you want to include 0 and 9?

Comment: [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) Check this out.

Comment: If you've done it in C before, you've got the hard bit sorted out, the rest of the code will be quite similar to the C implementation, except that writing to standard out can be achieved with `System.out.println()`.

Answer (score 1):

First there is no need for this part:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
        arrayBox[i]=0;
}
```

the array will by default be populated by 0's.

For part 2 and 3:

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random(seed);
for (int idx = 0; idx < 1000; idx++){
  int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
  arrayBox[randomInt] = arrayBox[randomInt] + 1
}
```

Part 4:

```
for(int i =0; i< 10; i++){
   System.out.println("amount of "+i+" is "+arrayBox[i]);
}
```

--edit--
As response to your comment, the Random class in Java is in itself an implementation of LGC and considered as one of the better ones. The constants are hardcoded as

```
fact = 25214903917
constant = 11
```

These numbers have been chosen after lots of testing and I'm sure you can find a lot of documentation about it on the internet.

In your case you have 2 options. Either force `Random` to use your constants or write it yourself. Option 1 will give you a weaker version of the Random class but which will still be 'stronger' then option 2.

For 1:

```
public class RandomCustom extends Random{

    //You have to Override this aswell.
    @Override
    synchronized public void setSeed(long seed) {
        this.seed.set(initialScramble(seed));
        haveNextNextGaussian = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected int next(int bits){
        long oldseed, nextseed;
        AtomicLong seed = this.seed;
        do {
            oldseed = seed.get();
            nextseed = (oldseed * fact + constant) & modulus;
        } while (!seed.compareAndSet(oldseed, nextseed));
        return (int)(nextseed >>> (48 - bits));
    }
}
```

After this just change `Random` from the code at the top in `RandomCustom` and you are ready.

In my opinion tho, why try to reinvent the wheel instead of using something that has been proven to be solid and working

Comment: I am trying to implement a Linear Congruential Generator actually, which is why i need the user input for Fact, Constant, Modulus and Seed for use in the following equation:
seednumber=(((fact*seednumber)+constant)%modulus);

Comment: In that case what u can do is take a look at the code from the Random class. Just Overwrite the next() method and use the parameters you received from input. I'll update my answer with a possible code example.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to use the Random class, you do not need all these input parameters. All you need is a long seed and the modulo to use for the generation (and if required the number of generations):

```
import java.util.*;

public class RandomNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input Long Seed: ");
        long seed = scan.nextLong();

        System.out.println("Input Modulus: ");
        int modulus = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Number of Iterations: ");
        int iterations = scan.nextInt();

        int[] arrayBox =new int[modulus];

        Random random = new Random(seed);

        for (int i=0;i<iterations;i++){
            arrayBox[random.nextInt(modulus)]++;
        }

        for (int i=0; i<modulus; i++){
            System.out.println("arrayBox["+i+"]="+arrayBox[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually imperatively need all these input parameters as asked to generate the numbers. I will then move on to work on the testing of it. I cannot let it just randomly select the values, it is part of cryptography.